# How to join a Series to a DataFrame: cannot append a non-category item to a CategoricalIndex

Tags: pandas

I think I'm following the instructions to a t but I still get this error I don't understand. I have a DatFrame and a Series, both with the same MultiIndex consisting of levels "Woche" and "cluster":

```
DataFrame "weekly":

Cat            Base  Major
Woche cluster
18w46 0         9.0    NaN
      D         5.0    NaN
      E        35.0    NaN
      F         7.0   50.0
      G        80.0   15.0

Series "df2":

Woche  cluster
18w46  0           9
       D           4
       E           1
       F           5
       G          94
Name: Bruch, dtype: int64

weekly = weekly.join(df2)
```

gives this error: TypeError: cannot append a non-category item to a CategoricalIndex.

I don't get it. weekly.index.is_categorical() and df2.index.is_categorical() both yield False.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem might be that `weekly.columns` -- the columns, not the index -- is a `CategoricalIndex`.
For example,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

nan = np.nan

weekly = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Woche": ["18w46", "18w46", "18w46", "18w46", "18w46"],
        "cluster": ["0", "D", "E", "F", "G"],
        "Base": [9.0, 5.0, 35.0, 7.0, 80.0],
        "Major": [nan, nan, nan, 50.0, 15.0],
    }
).set_index(["Woche", "cluster"])
weekly.columns = pd.CategoricalIndex(weekly.columns)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Woche": ["18w46", "18w46", "18w46", "18w46", "18w46"],
        "cluster": ["0", "D", "E", "F", "G"],
        "Bruch": [9, 4, 1, 5, 94],
    }
).set_index(["Woche", "cluster"])["Bruch"]

weekly.join(df2)
```

raises `TypeError: cannot append a non-category item to a CategoricalIndex`.

---

If `weekly.columns.is_categorical()` is `True`, the problem could be avoided by making `weekly.columns` a regular `pd.Index`:

```
weekly.columns = weekly.columns.tolist()
```